# Replacing certain fixed String in java

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a string query which looks like this

> {"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"terms":{"user.id":[#users_to_follow],"minimum_match":1}},{"terms":{"tweets":[#keywords_to_track],"minimum_match":1}}]}},"filter":{"range":{"publishedDate":{"from":#Unix_timestamp}}},"size":#sizelength}"

I am trying to replace certain strings in the query with another string using:

```
query.replace("#users_to_follow",usersToFollow);
query.replace("#keywords_to_track", keyworsToTrack);
query.replace("#Unix_timestamp","1325930428000" );
query.replace("#sizelength",Integer.toString(SMLApplicationProperties.ES_RESULTSET_SIZE));
```

However when I run this thing, it does not actually replace the given strings from query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to understand that String class is immutable. Any operation on String returns a new String. You need to assign it back to query variable:

```
query = query.replace("#users_to_follow",usersToFollow); 
query = query.replace("#keywords_to_track", keyworsToTrack); 
query = query.replace("#Unix_timestamp","1325930428000" ); 
query = query.replace("#sizelength",Integer.toString(SMLApplicationProperties.ES_RESULTSET_SIZE));
```

Comment: so when i do query=query.replace(); it does not returns the new changed string?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the result of the `replace` operation :

```
query = query.replace("#users_to_follow",usersToFollow);
```

That's because `query.replace` doesn't change the string you pass, it builds and returns a new one (string in java are immutable).

Comment: so i need to assign my query.replace() to a new string?

Comment: It IS a new String. You can use the same variable, as in my example. Simply add `query =` before the `query.replace`

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize (not accepted by everybody) :

```
String query = query.replace("#users_to_follow",usersToFollow).replace("#keywords_to_track", keyworsToTrack).replace("#Unix_timestamp","1325930428000" ).replace("#sizelength",Integer.toString(SMLApplicationProperties.ES_RESULTSET_SIZE));
```